# Extract all numbers from a character string into a SINGLE character string of numbers in the original order

Tags: r, string

I want to extract all numbers from a string into a single string in their original order. For example, from `"123hello456"` I would get `"123456"`

Comment: `gsub('\\D', '', '123hello456')`

Comment: @RonakShah please comment on why this works and it's a full blown answer.